# `chrome.downloads.search` is missing file results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, brave

In the context of a Chrome extension, I want to map some local downloaded files to in-storage data.

I'm having trouble understanding why a file that is clearly in the desired folder according to my OS would not be detected by `chrome.downloads.search`?

```sh
❯ ls ~/Downloads/PaperMemoryStore/*2101*
/Users/victor/Downloads/PaperMemoryStore/2101.02464.pdf
```

```js
const allfiles = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.downloads.search(
        { filenameRegex: "PaperMemoryStore/.*" }, 
        (p) => resolve(p))
    )
});
allfiles.filter(f => f.filename.includes("2101")) // [] <- empty filter
```

I understand why `allfiles` may have *more* results than what the filesystem shows (because of `DownloadItem.state` for instance) but not why it would show fewer.

Is it possible that `chrome.downloads.search` would not return files that have not been downloaded but just put in a folder? I could not find any such information [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-search).

Scenario:

1. I downloaded a pdf (`2101.02464.pdf`)
2. Which I copy-pasted in a sub-folder of `Downloads/` (`PaperMemoryStore`)
3. I'm running Brave `Version 1.36.122 Chromium: 99.0.4844.88 (Build officiel) (x86_64)`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the error and state property.
[Can't search chrome DownloadQuery with the error: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74867192/cant-search-chrome-downloadquery-with-the-error-property)
I think it's a bug. To overcome this issue, search with the blank query to get all download items and then loop across all items and check the array one by one.

On manifest v3, chrome.downloads.search return results as promised. Just omit the callback.

```
let results = chrome.downloads.search({});
let filters = results.filter(log => log.filename.includes("2101"));
```