# Can't search chrome DownloadQuery with the error: property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can search the others properties. eg. state, limit, danger, exists.

```
chrome.downloads.search({state: 'in_progress'});
chrome.downloads.search({state: 'interrupted', limit: 50});
chrome.downloads.search({exists: true});
```

But with the error: property, it returned all results.

```
chrome.downloads.search({error: 'USER_CANCELED'});
chrome.downloads.search({error: 'CRASH'});
```

Is it possible to search state: interrupted and all network errors at the same time?

```
chrome.downloads.search({state: 'interrupted', error: 'NETWORK_DISCONNECTED', error: 'NETWORK_FAILED', error: 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like Chrome bugs.

1. state: 'interrupted'. It didn't return all the interrupted items.
2. error: property bug. It will return all download items.

I fixed this by querying all items and using .filter

```
// [BUG] state: 'interrupted' didn't return all the interrupted items.
// [BUG] error: property will return all download items.

// let searchInProgress  = chrome.downloads.search({state: 'in_progress'});
// let searchInterrupted = chrome.downloads.search({state: 'interrupted'});

let searchDownloads = chrome.downloads.search({});  // Fixed bugs by query all download items in one shot and using filter.

searchDownloads.then(function (results)
{
    let downloading = results.filter(log => log.state === 'in_progress');
    let interrupted = results.filter(log => log.error !== 'USER_CANCELED' && log.error !== undefined);

    let count = downloading.length;
    let error = interrupted.length;

    console.log(results);
    console.log('in_progress : ' + count);
    console.log(downloading);
    console.log('interrupted : ' + error);
    console.log(interrupted);
});
```

Comment: Since it's a bug, have you considered reporting it? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list